# xamarin.forms detect ios app entering foreground from background

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am creating app in `Xamarin.Forms` shared proeject. I want to detect app when it comes from background

currently, I have implemented `OnActivated` method in `AppDelegate` but this method is also called when we open control center in iphone. I want my app to reconnect with my server when app comes to foreground from background and show message accordingly but this message is also shown when I swipe up and open control center.

In native `Xamarin.iOS` app, there is a method `WillEnterForegroundNotification` but this method is not available here.

Is there any method that's called only if app comes from background ?

Comment: Have you tried overriding `public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)` in your `AppDelegate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In native Xamarin.iOS app, there is a method
>   WillEnterForegroundNotification but this method is not available here.

You can access `WillEnterForegroundNotification`  method in Xamarin.forms project, just override it in `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    //
    // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    // visible.
    //
    // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    //
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication uiApplication)
    {   
        //handle your event here 
        base.WillEnterForeground(uiApplication);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

in `App.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void OnResume()
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, same behaviour happens in `OnResume`. It's called even if I try to change wifi or play some music(control center)

Comment: I am broadcasting an event during "OnResume" using Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter and subscribe wherever I need to handle the event.